# Error in running opencv code in target

Tags: yocto

I am currently working on yocto project. 
Am running my OpenCV code in ARM. am using `meta-ti` and `meta-openembedded` layer am getting error like:

> OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: your gstreamer installation is missing a required plugin
>   ) in handlemessage, file /usr/src/debug/opencv/3.1+gitAUTOINC+92387b1ef8-r0/git/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 1692
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /usr/src/debug/opencv/3.1+gitAUTOINC+92387b1ef8-r0/git/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1692: error: (-2) GStreamer:n
>    in function handlemessage.

I am using `bitbake core image-sato`
the code is cross compiled with toolchain and i build it.. is working fine but it showing error on board.
it asking `gstreamer` but `gstreamer` is already there in `meta-oe` there..

Comment: It's not asking for gstreamer, it's saying you don't have all the required plugins (without mentioning which ones are missing). You'll have to find out which plugins opencv needs and install the packages that provide those. Some potential recipes (on current yocto) are gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad and gstreamer1.0-libav.